# GitHub - прошу разъясните что именно я могу хранить в репозиториях

Tags: java, github

Суть вопроса следующая: начинаю разбираться с ГитХабом и просто нагуглив не могу найти ответа на свой вопрос. Сейчас я учу Java и мне не совсем понятно в каком формате мне хранить мой код в репозиториях Гит Хаба чтобы его можно было просто скопировать или вроде того. TXT? JAR? и т.д. если есть какой то ресурс, в котором можно что-то про это почитать, то буду очень благодарен.
В дополнение к вопросу еще один момент: как принято хранить Java проекты при работе в команде через GitHub

Comment: Надо не "вроде того", а определиться, зачем вам вообще нужен гитхаб. Если вы хотите поделиться своим проектом с сообществом, то, логично, в репозитории должен быть минимально необходимый набор, позволяющий собрать и запустить проект (исходный код, список зависимостей и т.п.)

Comment: @Jknock Garon , чтобы дополнить свой вопрос - отредактируйте его, а не оставляйте комментарии.

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На гитхабе храните исходный код проекта, а в .gitignore добавьте файлы, которые не нужны в публичном доступе другим участникам проекта/обозревателям. (напрамер системные папки, которые генерирует ваша среда разработки) так же в .gitignore можно добавить .env файлы, если необходимо скрыть персоональные ключи доступа и т.д В общем всю папку с исходным кодом проекта как правило хранят в гитхабе, а то что необходимо скрыть добавляется в .gitignore

Проект должен быть на гитхабе в таком виде, чтобы другие люди могли его скопировать к себе и запустить, а так же при необходимости поправить исходный код. Если вы можете скопировать свой проект к себе с гитхаба и он у вас полноценно запустится, то вы всё правильно сделали.

Хорошим тоном будет README.MD файлик с описанием проекта, как его запускать и пользоваться.

Посмотрите другие публичные примеры проектов на гитхабе, попробуйте их клонировать к себе и запустить, вам сразу станет понятно.

В каком формате? В том же что и исходные файлы вашего проекта.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за объяснение!